# Read/Write to a text file from Android application in C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, text-files, read-write

I am creating a mobile application which will read and write to and from text files in a Xamarin Android application using Visual Studio 2017. I don't know which file path should be used, as AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory does not seem to work and I'm not sure why or whether it should, although it did work for a Windows Console application. What file path do I use for this task? And how do I create the separate directory for the text file I want to write to?

When trying to merely display the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory as a String, I receive this error:

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> occurred
```

Comment: As i am sure you have already researched and read this, i thought id just leave it here anyway [File Storage and Access with Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/)

Comment: From my understanding, the System.Environment.SpecialFolder is what I should use, but i don't know how I can test with this in the emulator.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? i.e. To create/read/write a private/secure file within your Android sandboxed app or a public file available to all.

Comment: @SushiHangover The first one, create/read/write a private/secure file within the Android sandboxed app

Comment: See this guide for Xamrin.Forms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=macos, and testing in the emulator should be identical to testing on device.